# Recursive find node function

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I have a function that is recursively searching through a general tree (not BST) to find a specific Node, but it is not working properly. Each Node has an array of pointers to Nodes (children) and the default is set to 3 children for each Node. I know this is not the best way to do this but its part of an assignment. This function gets called by an insert function. The insert function gets passed in the name of the parent and then the find function finds the Node for that parent and returns it; the insert function then inserts the new child at that parent.

It seems to be working in most cases but for one of the new children the wrong node is returned by the find function. I walked through the debugger and it finds the matching parent name and returns like it is supposed to but then by the time it gets all the way back to the insert function (where it was called from) it is pointing to a different Node (not the one it originally found that was a match)

```
//Finds the name of the parent that is passed in and inserts a new node as a child of      that parent
void Tree::Tree(char* name,char* desc,int level,char* parentName)
{
    //find the parent
    Node* location = FindLoc(parentName, root);

    //the parent was found
    if(location)
    {
        int index = 0;

        while(location->child[index] && (index + 1) < child_max)
            ++index;

        if(!location->child[index])
        {
            location->child[index] = new Node();
            location = location->child[index];
            location->data.SetName(name);
            location->data.SetDesc(desc);
            location->data.SetLevel(level);
        }
    }

    else
        cout<< "Parent not found!"<<endl;
}


//Finds the parent of the new child to be added to the tree
Tree::Node* Tree::FindLoc(char* parentName, Node* root)
{
    Node* temp = NULL;
    if(root)
    {
        if(strcmp(parentName, root->data.GetName()) == 0)
            return root;
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < child_max && root->child[i]; ++i)
                temp = FindLoc(parentName, root->child[i]);

            if(temp) return temp;
        }
    }

    else return temp;
}
```

Comment: I'm not really a fan of homework assignments.  in your for(int i = 0; i < child_max && root->child[i]; ++i), you should bring the 'if(temp)' into the for loop, so you exit when you find it.

Comment: That fixed that problem but not it is not inserting at a different spot. When I try to find a node that is at                        `root->child[0]->child[1]`, it never seems to even visit that node.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your for loop to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < child_max; ++i)
    if(root->child[i])
    {
        temp = FindLoc(parentName, root->child[i]);
        if(temp) return temp;
    }
```